# Pairwise independence implies intependence of unions

Tags: probability

Is the following statement true?

> Let $\mathcal{A}$, $\mathcal{B}_1$, $\mathcal{B}_2$ be $\sigma$-algebras such that $\mathcal{A}$ is independent from $\mathcal{B_1}$ and $\mathcal{B}_2$. Then $\mathcal{A}$ is independent form $\sigma\{\mathcal{B}_1\cup\mathcal{B}_2\}$.

Of course for any $B\in\mathcal{B}_1\cup\mathcal{B}_2$ and $A\in\mathcal{A}$ we have $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$ since $B\in\mathcal{B}_1$ or $B\in\mathcal{B}_2$. But form there I can't conclude the statement above since $\mathcal{B}_1\cup\mathcal{B}_2$ is not $\cap$-stable. I could consider sets of the form $B_1\cap B_2$ for $B_i\in\mathcal{B}_i$ but for those I can't apply the independence condition immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If true this would imply that three random variables pairwise independent are always independent. One (should) know(s) this fails.

Counterexample: $\mathcal A=\sigma(Y)$ with $Y=X_1X_2$, and $\mathcal B_i=\sigma(X_i)$ where $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent symmetric Bernoulli random variables. Then $\mathcal A$ is independent of each $\mathcal B_i$ (*can you check this?*) but $\mathcal A\subset\sigma(\mathcal B_1\cup\mathcal B_2)$ (*can you check this?*) and $\mathcal A$ is not trivial hence $\mathcal A$ is not independent of $\sigma(\mathcal B_1\cup\mathcal B_2)$ (*can you check this?*).